# Php and openldap get more specific error code for an expired password

Tags: php, openldap

I have some trouble getting a more specific error number for a ldap password expired policy. In fact what i receive is error number 49 even if the password is wrong or the password is expired and needs to be changed.

I'm using a openldap server and php ldap functions. (ldap_bind, ldap_error and ldap_errno)

I've also tried to get some extra info by using ldap_get_option($connect, 0x0032, $extended_error) without success.

Is there any config that i have to do in my ldap server so it will return a more specific error number or a method to get the reason of Invalid credential error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With the password policy overlay you can configure it to send back a lockout error code.  See http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html ppolicy_use_lockout lockout option.  Another nice feature you can implement is password expiration warning and grace logins.  The expiration warning is a little trickier to implement.  It basically involves reading a response control that comes back from the bind request.  If you're trying to do it on windows you'll need to make sure that the php ldap module is linking to an openldap client library rather than the winldap32.dll.  I don't know enough about php to say it is or isn't.  Suffice to say the winldap library is broken enough that using it with anything but Active Directory only works for the basics and you'll never be able to read response controls from a bind request.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use the extended modify-password operation, and process the extended response.

Comment: Can you be a little more precise please? How can i extend the modify password operation to be able to receive a more specific error code for different invalid credential message. A sample php code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @MohoraBogdan You don't have to extend it, you just have to use it. How you do that in PHP is another question.

Comment: I looked into the openldap sources and managed to recompile them with the extended error responses. It looks like the responses for this cases were not returned by default. Then, from php i used ldap_get_option($conn,$const,$ext_err), where $const=0x0032. This way i managed to take into account different situations in user authentication.